# Video app plays videos random, not in sequence

Tags: android, video

I have a video app. I need that the app play the videos in order (1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4) but when I install the app the videos runs in random (2,3,1,4,2,1,3,4,2,4,etc...).

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView_video);
    final Uri path1 = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.ivirtual.promotaxi/"
            +R.raw.intro);
    final Uri path2 = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.ivirtual.promotaxi/"
            +R.raw.intro2);
    final Uri path3 = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.ivirtual.promotaxi/"
            +R.raw.intro3);
    final Uri path4 = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.ivirtual.promotaxi/"
            +R.raw.intro4);

    videoView.setVideoURI(path1);
    videoView.start();

    videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            siguiente1();
        }
        private void siguiente1(){
            videoView.setVideoURI(path1);
            videoView.start();
            videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    siguiente2();
                }
            });
        }

        private void siguiente2() {
            videoView.setVideoURI(path2);
            videoView.start();
            videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    siguiente3();
                }
            });
        }
        private void siguiente3(){
            videoView.setVideoURI(path3);
            videoView.start();
            videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    siguiente4();
                }
            });

        }
        private void siguiente4(){
            videoView.setVideoURI(path4);
            videoView.start();
            videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    siguiente1();
                }
            });

        }
    });

}
```

}

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Uri path1 = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.ivirtual.promotaxi/"
                +R.raw.intro);
    private Uri path2 = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.ivirtual.promotaxi/"
                +R.raw.intro2);
    private Uri path3 = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.ivirtual.promotaxi/"
                +R.raw.intro3);
    private Uri path4 = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.ivirtual.promotaxi/"
                +R.raw.intro4);

    private Uri uri_table[] = { path1, path2, path3, path4 };

    private VideoView videoView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView_video);
        Video();
    }

    private OnCompletionListener mOnCompletionListener = new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            Video();
        }
    }; // mOnCompletionListener

    private void Video() {
        Uri uri = 0;         // :P
        switch (signature_id) {
        case 0:
            uri = uri_table[1];
            break;
        case 1:
            ...
        case 4:
            uri = uri_table[0];
            break;
        }
    videoView = MediaPlayer.create(this, i);
    videoView.setOnCompletionListener(mOnCompletionListener);       
    videoView.start();
    }
```